# Find T^2 quantiles for multivariate data in R

Tags: r, multivariate-testing

I have a T^2 statistic for a partitioned multivariate dataset with 2 variables, found by calculating a paired comparison test. I want to compare my T^2 number with the T^2_{.95, p, n-1} value, without using a table.

Is there a function or package in R that allows me to find these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution#Hotelling.27s_T-squared_statistic), the T^2 statistic is related to the F statistic via

[image]

where [image].

From this it follows that (and is also written in the article)

> In order to calculate a p-value, multiply the t2 statistic by the above constant and use the F-distribution.

Ie if you isolate $t^2$ above, you can just find `qf(.95, p, n - p) * (n-1) * p / (n - p)` and it should be the relevant T^2 quantile.

Just be careful to read the article and make sure your degrees of freedom match up appropriately.

Comment: That's what I've been doing as  a workaround. I was hoping there was a direct way to do it without making the conversion to the F statistic.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with it. It doesn't "use a table", and gives an *exact* value. Just make a function `qt2(...)` that hides the calculation away if you like. (Any package you find for this statistic will almost certainly juts do this anyway).

Comment: There's certainly nothing wrong with it. Thank you for your help.